# iOS app for CNC Feeds & Speeds, compatible with Shapeoko

Tags: ios, iphone-app, cad, cam

I've been using GWizard Trial on my desktop, but the [CNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_control) is out in my garage. Would be great to have an app that did the same - i'm willing to pay.

There are too many to choose from on the app store, and many are for industrial CNC whereas I have a hobby CNC Shapeoko. Gwizard has Shapeoko3 settings - but no iOS app!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I had proprietary software that only ran on an old version of windows on an old PC but needed to access it on remote sites (and I didn't want to try to get an old laptop just to run the software and waste time on driver incompatibility, etc.)

The solution I used was a tablet (iPad mini) that I had a rugged bluetooth keyboard ([Zagg](https://www.zagg.com/us/en_us/rugged-book-ipad-mini/29106)) connected to using TeamViewer:

- [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/products/teamviewer/)

... worked like a charm.  My recommendation is use remote viewer software & then control it from a tablet (you can do it with your phone, but the screen is to small for my taste.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of feeds and speeds calculators at: https://wiki.shapeoko.com/index.php/Materials#Feed_and_Speed_Calculators

Some of them are online, and a quick search of the Apple Store revealed 3 (which in fairness may not have been available when this question was posted):

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cnc-machinist-calculator-pro/id1037668281
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/machinists-calculator/id687225532
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/machinist-calculator-sfm/id373899555

and this discussion: https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/cnc-machining/free-machinist-calculator-app-316406/ mentions another with a link.

Please note however that due to the limited rigidity of the machine in comparison with industrial machines, the calculators are of limited use. Winston Moy has an excellent video discussing this which is linked to from the Shapeoko wiki Materials page.